# appending to rescue_responses in an Rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two custom exceptions I'm trying to add to `Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses` in an engine.

```
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!({
  'Exceptions::Unauthorized' => :unauthorized,
  'Exceptions::Forbidden' => :forbidden
})
```

The above works fine in the application, but when I put it in an initializer in the engine:

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!({
  'Exceptions::Unauthorized' => :unauthorized,
  'Exceptions::Forbidden' => :forbidden
})
```

It's ignored. I'm assuming because the engine's initializer is run before Rails sets the rescue_responses? Any ideas of what I can do differently?

Answer (score 1):

The `config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses` value is only used transiently. If you look in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/railtie.rb#L36 it's merged into `ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses` in an initializer block, which is evaluated before any initializer scripts :-(

If you look at e.g. ActiveRecord, they set it in the `Railtie` file: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L25

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to tune `ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses` in application initializers. This is where configuration value ends up and this behavior is confirmed in [this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22613).

But in case of a library, its railtie should append to `config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses`.